# Post form, wait ten seconds and redirect to

Tags: javascript, http-post

I have a page that need to do the following steps:

Step 1 - Receive URL address, name, value, num and ID via `POST`

Step 2 - Wait 10 seconds

Step 3 - Send (also via post) the following info received via post: name, value, num and ID to the URL received via post

Step 4 - Redirect to the URL that received the post and print the post in the screen.

For this I'm using the code below, but anything is going wrong, because the print in the redirected URL, that should bring the post info is coming empty, so it looks like that for any reason the info is not being posted correctly.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

HTML - Create the Form to POST:

```
<form id="ret" name="return_url" method="post" action="<?php print_r($_POST['url']);?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php print_r($_POST['name']);?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="value" value="<?php print_r($_POST['value']);?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="num" value="<?php print_r ($_POST['num']);?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php print_r($_POST['ID']);?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="status" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Add the posted url content to the var `$retorno` that will be used in Javascript (PHP):

```
<?php
    $retorno = $_POST['url'];
?>
```

Start the counter, submit the form and redirect (using javascript):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    function countdown() {
      if (typeof countdown.counter == 'undefined') {
        countdown.counter = 10; // initial count
      }
      if (countdown.counter > 0) {
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = countdown.counter--;
        setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("ret").submit();
        location.href = '<?php echo $retorno?>';
      }
    }
    countdown();
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with your code.

**1. You use `print_r` where you should use `echo`**

```
<form id="ret" name="return_url" method="post" action="<?php print_r($_POST['url']);?>">
```

In the line above `print_r` will output the content of `$_POST['url']` in a way that will be invalid as an `action` attribute value. **Look at the HTML source code of the generated page.**

This should be rewritten as:

```
<form id="ret" name="return_url" method="post" action="<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>">
```

You make that same mistake with all your input values. The action value is especially important as it must be the address where the form is POSTed.

**2. You submit the form but you also redirect the page**

You have a conflict between the form `submit()` and the redirect with `location.href`

Simply remove the `location.href` line. If your HTML form is properly configured the JavaScript `submit()` will send the browser to the page defined in the `action` attribute.

Lastly I would advise you to look at the jQuery library to make JavaScript coding easier.